# A State space model for discrete Sine wave Using kalma filter

Tags: kalman-filters, state-space

I'm looking to apply an optimal LQR filter to a discrete signal of the form
$$
x[n]=A\sin(\omega_0n+\phi)+v[n]
$$
The amplitude $A$ and the phase $\phi$ are unknown variables I want to estimate using the filter, and $v[n]$ is an uncorrelated noise signal of variance $\sigma_v^2$.

I don't know how to build a state model to generate this sine wave, and proceed from there.

Comment: I did something similar in the past except we wanted to track the frequency. From what I recall we used 4 states

states : Amplitude, derivate of x[n], frequency, frequency derivate

Comment: Is $\omega_0$ known?

Comment: Yes $\omega_0$ is known

Comment: @Ben Please could you explain how you did that better? Any materials to help on this ? I am still confused.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nonlinear Kalman filter, such as the [extended Kalman filter (EKF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter), and track the phase and frequency as your state variables.

In this case, your Kalman filter is essentially acting like a phase-locked loop (PLL).

[Example reference](http://oodgeroo.ucsd.edu/~bob/estimation/Estimation_Winter_2015/Notes_and_docs_files/P61_Barb_TSP.pdf)